# How to fix dpkg error (1)

Tags: server, upgrade, dpkg, mysql, debian

To be honest i'm not using Ubuntu but Debian (7.8), but as the commands are almost alike and this doesn't seem like an OS related problem to me, I figured I'd ask it on this glorious forum.

I'm having a problem trying to upgrade my system. I've tried to run `apt-get upgrade -f` (this is all in root btw) but it return the following result:

```
root@*******:/# apt-get upgrade -f    
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
  mysql-server-5.5  
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
8 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/2,093 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
Reading changelogs... Done  
Preconfiguring packages ...  
(Reading database ... 77057 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to replace mysql-server-5.5 5.5.38-0+wheezy1 (using .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb) ...  
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!  
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.  
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1  
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...  
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!  
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.  
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1  
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!  
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.  
[ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld already running.  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0+wheezy1_amd64.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I've tried searching for dpkg returning error code (1) but I can't really seem to solve this specific case of it.

I hope someone is able to offer me the help I need, I would really appreciate it.

Kind Regards,
Remy

EDIT >>

@vembutech
I've tried looking into /var/lib/dpkg/status, and I I found the following about mysql-server-5.5 [http://pastebin.com/8DzKnY2x][1].

@Wang Xiaoyu
I only get the following lines when doing that command:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done

@octavian
When I try to stop mysqld I get the following error:

> root@149-210-180-7:~# service mysqld stop
>   mysqld: unrecognized service

Though when I try to stop mysql I get the following error:

> [FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!

Comment: Try with the following command and check whether dpkg status. sudo -i, 
gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status.

Comment: @vembutech I've replied with an edit

Comment: This slipped through migration but in future, please use http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was unaware of that subdomain, I will use that one in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like you need to stop / kill the MySQL database first, then update:

```
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!  
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
```

I'm not sure what the executable is called, but if it's got "sql" in it's name somewhere then running this should find it's pid (maybe among others):

```
ps aux | grep -i sql
```

Then try killing it (`kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>` or `sudo kill <pid>`, etc...) and another `ps` just in case it's re-spawned.

Then install & it should work...?

Comment: Thank you so much! After killing the running mysqld process with the kill command everything upgraded just fine!

Comment: No problem, the accepted answer/check-mark, + upvote is thanks enough :-) As to *why* mysqld wouldn't stop, I'm not sure. Searching for mysql-server-5.5 5.5.38-0+wheezy1 had a similar hit http://superuser.com/questions/502822/cant-start-mysql5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-dpkg-dependency-problems their answers were to replace "my-huge.cnf" with the original "my.cnf", or even purge *"all the mysql application"* and delete `/var/lib/mysql` but that would also delete your data/databse, so I don't like that idea without a good backup first (should backup before an upgrade too, to be a "perfect user" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you had `mysql-server-5.5` already installed, at least the daemon mysqld is running. `dpkg` fails to stop this daemon. Try stopping it manually before running `apt-get upgrade -f` via `sudo service mysqld stop`.

Comment: I've replied with an edit

Comment: Ok, let's check if the service is running at all: `ps aux | grep mysql`

Answer (score 0):

ok,it looks some wrong with installing. So, you can try

`dpkg -C` 
or 
`sudo apt-get check`

to find information about `error code 1.`

Comment: I've replied with an edit

Comment: i have found it which is `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) `.  you know , if `apt-get upgrade` operation generates some error code, such as error code(1), which can be found some log information by using `dpkg -C` command. are u sure to do `dpkg -C` command?